# How to map data with ggplot: Error in names[df$group, 1] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I am trying to plot data of US temperatures on a map of the US with various projections. All of them give me the same error: "Error in names[df$group, 1] : subscript out of bounds"

I tried changing the name from a .df to something else since I had a weird error with that earlier. I tried changing the parameters. I tried everything I can think of, but it doesn't specify which line the error is in. There are 3 variables and 56 observations. I am not missing any columns or rows.

```
conformal=map('state',proj='lambert',param=c(30,40))
ggplot(data=conformal)+
  geom_map(data=conformal, map=conformal,
           aes(x=lon, y=lat, map_id=region),
           color="black", fill="white", size=0.05)+
  geom_text(data=temp.df, aes(x=lon,y=lat))
```

I can get the map function to work, and I can change projections successfully, but the data will not plot on the maps!!!

Comment: Normally a `geom_text` layer requires a `label` aesthetic. You might also need to set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_text`, if `temp.df` doesn't have all the columns you've mapped from the `conformal` data. Does it work without the `geom_text` line? That's a good way to narrow down which line is causing the error...

Comment: @Gregor no I still get the same error when I delete the geom_text portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `map()` (presumably from the `maps` package) isn't something `ggplot()` can handle easily. You might be looking for something like this?

```
us <- map_data("state")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = us,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               color = "black", fill = "white") +
  # geom_text(data=temp.df, aes(x=lon,y=lat)) # commented out since we don't have temp.df
  coord_map(projection = "lambert", parameters = c(30, 40))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: so close!! my teacher insists we use ggplot. I did what you suggested and get a new error.. "Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`"

Comment: Do you get that error with the code above, or after un-commenting the line for `geom_text`? If the latter, do take note of @Gregor's comment that `geom_text` requires a `aes(label = <whatever the column name is, from temp.df>)`.

Comment: I took out the geom_text part. If I change one little thing it switches between that last error and "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (15537): x, y, group"

Comment: It's generally difficult to troubleshoot in the dark. Please be explicit.

Comment: I think you have a typo there: it should be `colour='black', fill='white'` rather than `colour=('black', fill='white')`. Also, `x = long` rather than `x = lon`. You can check the variable names with `colnames(conformal)` or `str(conformal)` if you aren't sure.